# creating a content portal with php and maybe mysql?

Tags: php, security, dynamic, remote-server, portal

So I have a server (server 1) that contains lots of dynamically generated content with php and I have another server (server 2) that needs access to that content. I'm trying to figure out the cleanest and most secure way to pass the content to server 2 when server 2 requests it.

I know you aren't allowed to use include to call a file from a remote server so I've been experimenting with file_get_contents but I don't know how safe that will be. I'm worried about security because I won't be having full control over server 2, only server 1 where the content is stored. I don't want server 2 to be able to write anything to these files or see the server-side code that generates the rendered content. I only want them to be able to print the output of the file requested from server 1.

I thought about using a database maybe somehow to store the content in a cell and then pull the output from there but I'm not 100% sure. I would kind of like to add a username/password auth to the portal file to ensure other people don't find it and abuse it but I don't know if the constant requests to the db checking for auth will hurt load time too badly.

The content being received from server 1 will be printed multiple times using loops in some cases.

Any help pointing me in the right direction will be greatly appreciated. I just want to do this right the first time and keep the content on server 1 safe from theft and modification by server 2. I will be adding all of my points as a bounty to this as well. Thank you again.

So right now my setup is like this:

```
(Server 1 Portal.php)

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://domain1.com/shared/css/style.css">
<?php
$fileName = $_GET["file"];

if ($fileName) {
   include ($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/shared/content/".$fileName.".php");
} else {
   echo "Missing file name.";       
}
?>

<script src="http://domain1.com/shared/js/functions.js"></script>
```

Then on server 2 I have something like this

```
(Server 2 index.php)
<?php
$test = file_get_contents('http://domain1.com/shared/portal.php?file=testfile');
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
   <?php echo $test; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: f_g_c doesn't execute code. it just returns a string of whatever you fetched. unless you do something boneheaded like `eval($test)`, there's nothing domain1.com can do to "execute" code on your server#2

Comment: what would eval($test) do? I tried it in my sample and received "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /homepages/5/d569633143/htdocs/index.php(3) : eval()'d code on line 2"

Comment: eval() runs a string as if it was php code. `eval('echo "foo"')` would print out the word `foo`. so basically `eval($test)` would run whatever the remot server sent back, and if they sent back `exec('rm -rf /')` you'd be happily nuking your server.

Comment: Ok well I'm server 1 and someone else is server 2. So assume I dont send back exec('rm-rf /') there wouldnt be any issues? lol

Comment: that's what I said. unless you do something boneheaded like RUNNING whatever the other server (the one you have on control over) sends back, all you're doing is getting some text and stuffing it into your page. that won't affect YOUR server, really, but it COULD affect whoever's viewing the page on your server. e.g. they could send back `<script>window.location='http://nastyillegalporn.com';</script>`

Comment: do you mean they could send back a script tag from server 2 to the file on server 1? @MarcB Using file_put_contents or something?

Comment: they can send back ANYTHING they want, since it's their server. and since you're spitting out the text they sent back directly into your page, they can have effective control of that page in the user's browser, and it'll appear to the user as if YOUR server is doing something bad, since the malicious text came from your site.

Comment: I think you're under the understanding that I have control over server 2 (the client)? I am server 1 (the host) which is giving the content to server 2 (the client). It's in my contract to not send over any sketchy content so they aren't worried about what I'm sending them. I'm only worried if they can send something back to me. Meaning from server 2 (the client) to server 1 (the host). @MarcB